# Why does the download speed goes over the ISP bandwidth speed?

Tags: download, bandwidth, isp

I have a wireless connection of 256 Kbps from my ISP. The download speed obviously varies on servers I am downloading from. But it goes all upto 181 KBps from ubuntu server and even higher from YouTube. How is it possible?

Comment: Convert both numbers to the same unit and you will see your ISP is giving you exactly what you are paying for.

Comment: @Ramhound Something's not adding up. 256 Kbps = 32 KBps. Yet OP's getting 181 KBps and higher. Way over the limit.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your ISP limit is 256 Kilo-bits-per-second? That's stupidly slow in 2015, even for wireless. You wouldn't even dare try YouTube at that speed, nothing would ever happen. Might pay to double check your numbers.

Comment: Who is your ISP? Are the 256 Kbps the maximum rate or a guaranteed minimum rate?

Comment: http://techminds.com.np/?page=itariff 
I am not sure. It's the first choice in the first table in the linked page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're getting 181 KBps (Kilo-Bytes-Per-Second) right? And even faster on some sites? This seems to indicates that your ISP limit is 256 KBps (again, Kilo-Bytes-Per-Second) and you're getting speeds close to that.

I suspect you're just confusing or mis-reading units. Besides, 256 Kilo-*Bits* (as you wrote it) is something you simply won't see in this day and age, that's absurdly slow. Unless... what country/city/location are you based in?!

** EDIT **

I stand corrected and I apologise. I have just looked at ISP plans in your region and, wow, you're right - 256 kbps is pretty standard stuff.

OK there are only a couple reasons why you're getting faster speeds than your plan:

1. Your ISP is being "nice" and allowing you faster download speed, perhaps during periods of low demand
2. Your ISP made a some kind of mistake when they set up your account, perhaps putting you on the wrong plan or selecting the wrong max speed. If this is true, you may even be charged accordingly so it may be worth checking in with them.

** LAST EDIT **

Based on on-going comments, there is a third possibility:

3. Your ISP has systems and possibly agreements in place with other companies that can allow them to provide you *selected* internet content faster than your plan speed.

Comment: That's not the case. I am signed up for 256 kilo bits for sec(every ISP I've known use Kbps not KBps for ad). Yes, it's ridiculously slow. I get an average of 230 k bytes per sec. on video download from YouTube.

Comment: @coder_Bibek I'm very sorry, you are quite right. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Then: are you sure you're signed for WLAN (Wifi) and not WWAN? If the latter, then yes - it's more probable to see ad in kbps. But that's still rare in those days. Most ads I see are always in MBps when talking about speed... with an asterisk, but still.

Anyway - if it's really WiFi, then... either you're on the back end of nowhere or it's a bad deal. I was offered 512kbps 4 years ago and ISP was very sorry it's all they could do, but it was 1,5 km to nearest AP... Also, they offered wired LAN access elsewhere and they limited outgoing (from network) speeds. Internally it was fast.

Comment: @coder_Bibek Do you mind me asking, I am curious, how do you actually watch YouTube videos on a slow connection like that? Do you use some kind of video download software so you can watch later off-line?

Comment: 2/2, and they offered proxy with cache, so often you could get stuff really fast as it was from local server, really.
EDIT: Ok, I can see where you come from as well. Stand corrected and impressed. Way to Go, guys. You getting ahead some places in the Europe...

Comment: @AcePL Actually, 256 kbps is pretty standard stuff in Nepal. http://kalopati.com/480/choosing-an-internet-service-provider-in-nepal/

Comment: Actually the youtube videos especially the ones that are popular(watched in my regions) stream without interruption in 480p and I that is it. And I think you're right, @misha256 , that ISP are being nice. Peer to peer download( like torrents) go only upto 35KBps at max.

Comment: @coder_Bibek Ahhhh it's all starting to make sense now :-)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense to me as well. And 3rd possibility seems most likely.

Answer (score -1):

The way you could test this is by using a peer2peer download that has hundreds of seeders, so the side at the other end will not be limited by anything. This way you will find you maximum actual speed in KB/s. If you say the limit is 256kbps, it can be actually exceeded because some browsers use compression algorithms that can cause misleading readings. Next, the value stated by ISP could be the minimum value guaranteed, not the maximum. So get back to what I said initially and test your speed. maybe even the limit is somehow gone.

Comment: You are right about the peer to peer downlaod. It gets upto 35KBps at max. But it should have to be pretty damn good compression algorithm to render above 200 KBps video stream from 32 KBps bandwidth, right? :)

Comment: Please also test your speed at speedtest.net . Since your connection is not fast, there should be no limitation from the servers end, making the result relevant.

Comment: http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/4128805454

Comment: @coder_Bibek Lol you're right, you'd need pretty amazing compression to get 200 KBps from 35 KBps. Actually it would have to be more than amazing, it would have to be magic seeing as those YouTube videos are already compressed :-p

Comment: @misha256 exactly. :D